# MATLAB struct array field access

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

I have an array of structures in MATLAB and I want to plot all of the values for one key. I know you can print it by doing `array.key` but for some reason `hist(array.key)` doesn't work.

Seems simple enough but I couldn't find how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
clear all
array(10).key = 1:10;
mat = [array.key]
hist(mat)
```

Try something like the above.

Comment: Oh my god thank you! Simple as that! Makes my life so much easier!

Comment: @akk if the answer helped you, it would be good to accept it.